# Hide overflow of pseudo-elements

Tags: html, css

I've made a fancy checkbox, which uses pseudo-elements to look nice, but unfortunately the `overflow: hidden` doesn't work well in its case. I don't know why.

Here's my code:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: black;
}

.priority {
    display: none;

}
.priority, .priority:after, .priority:before, .priority *, .priority *:after, .priority *:before, .priority + .priority-btn {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.priority + .priority-btn {
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    background: #666;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    height: 2.375em;
}

.priority + .priority-btn::after, .priority + .priority-btn::before {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}

.priority + .priority-btn::after {
    left: 100%;
    content: 'IMPORTANT';
}

.priority + .priority-btn::before {
    left: 0;
    content: 'UNIMPORTANT';
}

.priority + .priority-btn:active {
    background: #888;
}

.priority + .priority-btn:active::before {
    left: -10%;
}

.priority:checked + .priority-btn {
    background: #86d993;
}
.priority:checked + .priority-btn:before {
    left: -100%;
}
.priority:checked + .priority-btn:after {
    left: 0;
}
.priority:checked + .priority-btn:active:after {
    left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="checkbox" ngModel name="priority" id="priority" class="priority">
        <label class="priority-btn" for="priority"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the text comes out from the container label.

Comment: Not sure but would it be enough to add .col { overflow: hidden;} ? Is the problem with specific browser?

Comment: @Esko it can be enough because col has `position:relative` which make the pseudo element at least be relatively potionned to col ... all depend on the reference of the postion (relatively to what ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `position: relative` to the `.priority-btn` since its *pseudo-elements* have `position: absolute`:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: black;
}

.priority {
    display: none;

}
.priority, .priority:after, .priority:before, .priority *, .priority *:after, .priority *:before, .priority + .priority-btn {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.priority + .priority-btn {
    overflow: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    background: #666;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    height: 2.375em;
    position: relative;
}

.priority + .priority-btn::after, .priority + .priority-btn::before {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 11;
}

.priority + .priority-btn::after {
    left: 100%;
    content: 'IMPORTANT';
}

.priority + .priority-btn::before {
    left: 0;
    content: 'UNIMPORTANT';
}

.priority + .priority-btn:active {
    background: #888;
}

.priority + .priority-btn:active::before {
    left: -10%;
}

.priority:checked + .priority-btn {
    background: #86d993;
}
.priority:checked + .priority-btn:before {
    left: -100%;
}
.priority:checked + .priority-btn:after {
    left: 0;
}
.priority:checked + .priority-btn:active:after {
    left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="checkbox" ngModel name="priority" id="priority" class="priority">
        <label class="priority-btn" for="priority"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I deleted my answer, this is the real solution. If you give the parent element `overflow: hidden;', the pseudo-elements are still outside of the screen. Hiding the scrollbar doesn't fix it, it just "hides" it, which is not a clean fix. VXp's answer is :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works the same way as I've imagined... :)

Comment: I would probably add explanation to say that overflow:hidden doesn't consider Dom structure but also the position and the reference .. because adding the overflow to col wokrs also for the same reason

Comment: `It affects the clipping of all of the element's content except any descendant elements (and their respective content and descendants) whose containing block is the viewport or an ancestor of the element.` --> https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow. The *except* part is what needed here ;)

Comment: [**Here**](https://imgur.com/gallery/j6aSADM) is a visualization of the differences between VXp's clean fix and the fix with `{overflow: hidden;}`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:hidden` to your `.col` class

```
.col{
      overflow: hidden;

}
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything, the point is not in `overflow: hidden` since it's already applied where it needs to be.

Comment: yes you are right. Thanks